# Java generic interface with type constraint vs c# generics

Tags: c#, java, generics, interface, constraints

I came across some Java code similar to this:

```
public interface ITest<T1 extends IOne,T2 extends ITwo> {
    boolean handle(T1 value1);
    boolean handle(T2 value2);
}
public interface IOne {}
public interface ITwo {}
```

And then an implementation of ITest:

```
public class Test implements ITest {
@Override
public boolean handle(IOne value1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean handle(ITwo value2) {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Note the lack of type declaration in the "Test implements ITest". Coming from a c# world this surprised me as you can not do this in c#. You would have to write something like:

```
public class Test : ITest<IOne, ITwo>
```

I understand that Java generics are very different to c# generics but i would like to understand better what is happening in the Java code that allows the above code to compile? Is it type inference by the compiler? Is the raw type IOne and ITwo being used for the Test class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Thanks.

Comment: That should give you a compiler warning in Java.

Comment: @Servy: That's illegal in Java. (due to type erasure)

Comment: `I understand that Java generics are very different to c# generics` - Correct. java is a ridiculous joke while C# is a serious programming language. java generics are ugly, ridiculous, and useless because the actual type information is "erased" at compile time, which is just bizarre. While C# has true support for generics, and generics are compiled into the binaries mantaining type information at all stages.

Comment: @HighCore but... it's on the roadmap to not erase that information :-)

Comment: No warnings when compiling code. The code is as is, no generic/non generic version of interface.

Comment: Then Java is probably doing deeper type inference than C#.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm tired to hear "it's on the roadmap". It's been "on the roadmap" for 20 years now. They're trying to release features that C# already had by 2007.

Comment: @HighCore but... Java has a lot of built-in classes

Comment: @Domc: I get `ResponseParser.ITest is a raw type. References to generic type ResponseParser.ITest<T1,T2> should be parameterized` in Eclipse.

Comment: @SLaks: Your right. I was using IntelliJ and i don't get the compiler warning. Same code in Eclipse and i get a warning.

Comment: @JanDvorak so what? the .Net CLR also has a lot of built-in classes. From Entity Framework to WPF to ASP.Net to System.Security to System.GodKnowsWhat. That's got nothing to do with the language per se. java is still years behind C#. BTW, if you want to discuss the class libraries, please show me something even barely comparable to WPF in java.. please..

Comment: @domc so you're saying that java compilation results are different between different IDEs?? that's even worse.. how can anyone actually use that stuff for anything serious?

Comment: @HighCore hmm... some javascript library might be able to match WPF. But yeah, Swing sucks compared to WPF.

Comment: @JanDvorak javascript has NOTHING to do with java... wrong answer

Comment: @HighCore I never implied otherwise. The extensive class system is about the only thing I liked about Java... but then I learned C# has that and much more. But when I read about data binding, angular/knockout/backbone is what came into my mind, but that's Javascript, not Java.

Comment: @HighCore: Lets not get into a Java vs c# debate in the comments. Yes I do not get that warning in IntelliJ. I am no IntelliJ expert so i may have a setting which is hiding the warning. I wanted to understand what was happening in the code shown. The warning sheds some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When java compiles

`T1 extends IOne`

it replaces all instances of T1 with IOne

so

```
public boolean handle(T1 value1) {
    return false;
}
```

becomes

```
public boolean handle(IOne value1) {
    return false;
}
```

so the actual interface Itest is

```
public interface ITest {
    boolean handle(IOne value1);
    boolean handle(ITwo value2);
}
```

It can do this because an instance of T1 will always be able to be assigned to IOne and an instance of T2 will always be able to be assigned to ITwo.

When compiling Test it is looking for methods that match the concrete methods in the interface and does not complain because it finds methods that satisfy what it is looking for.

Comment: Extending your answer after further reading. As you said all instances of T1 are replaced with IOne. Type Eraser does this "the 
Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html. Because the type T1 is bound to IOne all instances of T1 are replaced with IOne and not Object.  This is the Raw Type (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and it does produce a compiler warning as mentioned by SlakS.

Comment: Compiler warnings can be compiler specific. Neither javac nor intellij  appear to generate a warning.

Comment: Just to add to this, the erasure means that you can't have a single method that takes a `List<T>` and determine what `T` is at runtime through reflection.